# Mode and median of a discrete random variable - Exercise

Tags: probability, statistics, median

I've the random variable $X=(0,25,25,50,100)$. Is it correct to say that:

$$
mode = 25
$$

and

$$
median = 25
$$

because $P(X \leq 25) = 2/5 = 0.4$ ?

Comment: The median is 25 'cause there are 5 data and the third one (the central value) is 25.
The mode is 25, since is the only data that is duplicate.

Comment: Hello @TitoEliatron thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: Several slightly different definitions of sample quantiles are in use. However, for your data, I believe they all agree that the median (quantile 50) is 25. //But be a little careful: For data (0, 10, 24, 26, 50, 100), the generic definition is that **a** median is any value in $[24,26].$ To give a single number as **the** median, some statistical programs will give $24,$ some will give $25.,$ and still others that I didn't try might give $26$ or other values in $[24,26].$